# How to upload file into File View on Ambari Web?

Tags: centos, vagrant, hadoop

1. I am using HDP 2.6 and ambari 2.5. on a 5 node cluster. The cluster was setup with vagrant following these instructions

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Quick+Start+for+New+VM+Users . The base box is Centos 7.0

My host machine is running Centos 7.3

2. I am trying to use File View and I cannot upload a file. I get:

   Unauthorized connection for super-user: root from IP 192.168.70.104
3. In Ambari Web. I logged in admin/admin. I have followed the instructions

https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.1.0.0/bk_ambari_views_guide/content/_configuring_your_cluster_for_files_view.html and created a proxy for admin, I changed the settings to 777. I also added admin as a user of this File View instance.

4. I have the sandbox setup and I can upload files on the sandbox.
5. If I vagrant ssh c7001.ambari.apache.org (node with ambari-server running) I can put a file into the hdfs and it shows up in the File View under /user/admin (The default directory that I set up see (3). )

However, I cannot upload anything from my local filesystem with File Views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, hadoop.proxyuser.root.hosts=c7001.ambari.apache.org and not *. Changing this value to * allows me to upload files.

john